# Jquery: Accessing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to access a div with class="emailSent", but I am not able to reach the div.

Here is the HTLML code generated with a while loop in php:

```
    <tr><td>TR 1</td></tr><tr>
    <td colspan="7">
        <div class="replyDiv" align="center" style="display:none; margin:10px 60px 10px 10px;">

            <form width="350px" id="userReplyForm" name="userReplyForm" method="post" action="#">
            <input type="hidden" id="date" name="date" value="'.time().'"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="sender" name="sender" value="'.$username.'"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="recipient" name="recipient" value="'.$sender.'"/>
            <table align="center" width="350px" class="smallTxt userDetails">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="350px"><input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size=30 value="RE:'.$subject.'"/></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="350px"><textarea rows="6" cols="42" id="message" name="message"></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="submitBtnSmallLong" value="Send Reply"/></td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="emailSent" align="center" style=" margin:10px 60px 10px 10px; color:blue; font-size:18px;">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So what I have is 2 rows of tables being generated for every record. How can I access ONLY the corresponding divs for that record 
(I don't want to update all divs in rows, just that one being worked on): 
1.) div with class "replyDiv" ?? 
2.) div with class "emailSent"  ??

I ve tried accessing the divs directly with $(".replyDiv").hide(); but its not working.

Ok, here is the jQuery part:

```
    $(function(){//getUserReply, send to process.php
        $("form").submit(function(){
            var dataString = $(this).serialize();
            var message = $(this).find("#message").val();

        if(message==""){alert("Please enter your message");
            }else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "process.php",
                action: "submitForm",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: "JSON",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == "true"){//hide replyDiv and show emailSent div
                        $("form").closest("tr").find(".emailSent").append("hello"); //this line appends hello to all the .emailSent divs. Remember, I have many rows so only want this particular div being shown.                      
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            });

        }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Ok, so I ve found out that if I use $("form").closest("tr").find(".emailSent").append("hello"); this will access ALL the divs with className .emailSent.  So now, I just have to find out a way to access only that PARTICULAR div and not all

Comment: The question is, from *where* / *when* do you want to access the elements? You write *How can I access ONLY the corresponding divs for that record* so you must be working at a specific at the moment you want to access those elements. E.g. do you want to access the elements when the form is submitted? Or a certain button is pressed?

Comment: FelixKing, the point of origin is in the replyDiv. The user selects the CORRESPONGING mail, say at row 5, then types in their message, hits submit. I then send this data to a php page to process, and if everything comes back ok, under the success: function(){ //here I want to hide the .replyDiv and show the .emailSent div for that PARTICULAR current row ONLY, with a message sent successfully or something of that nature//} how can I achieve this

Comment: @Johny, how do they select the corresponding mail? What is the triggering element?

Comment: @Johny: Please see my answer and tell me if I'm correct ;) Btw, it would be good if you post the JavaScript code you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Here is a version of your code that should work (basically it is just applying what I wrote below, I also restructured it a bit):

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <- better than `return false`

    // get reference to elements:
    var $replyDiv = $(this).parent();
    var $emailSent = $(this).parent().next();
    // or
    // var $emailSent = $(this).closest('td').find('.emailSent');

    // you should give the form elements classes!
    if(!$(this).find("#message").val()){
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url:  "process.php", // `action` does not exist as option
           data:  $(this).serialize(),
           dataType: "JSON",
           cache: false,
           success: function(data){
              if(data == "true"){//hide replyDiv and show emailSent div
                $replyDiv.hide();
                $emailSent.append('hello').show();                   
              }
           }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter your message");
    }
});
```

---

Based on your last comment, I assume you are going to send the form data to the server via an Ajax request and you want to access some specific information in the `success` callback.

```
$('.replyDiv form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //                form           emailSent
    //                  v               v
    var $emailSent = $(this).parent().next();
    //                         ^
    //                     replyDiv

    $.ajax({
        //...
        success: function() {
            // here you want the reference
            $emailSent.text('Worked!');
        }
    });
});
```

---

Btw. if you really have multiple of these rows, then you must not give the form elements IDs.

Comment: Yes, something like that! I will post this part to my original post. Please see what my mistake is there

Comment: Oh my God! I am a genius...well, all of you guys are Geniuses, lol. Thanks a lot all. It's working! Thanks Felix. I really liked the way you structured my code man! I hope one day my code will be efficiently written as yours - for now, I am still a noob on the learn.

Comment: @Johny: Your're welcome :) Interestingly enough, it seems I can always better structure other peoples code than my own ;) Btw. you should accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking the tick outline next to it. You mark your question as solved with that (you should do this for every question that has a satisfying answer, so also your previous question (if it was solved)).

Comment: One last question for future reference: when you use (this) keyword, does "this" always refer to the current element you're working with?

Comment: @Johny: Yes, in the event handlers you attach with jQuery, `this` always refers to the *DOM element* the event was raised on. So we need to call `$(this)` to make it a jQuery object (if you want to use jQuery methods).

Answer (score 2):

Look at your code, you are defining it as a class not as a id

```
<div class="emailSent" align="center" style=" margin:10px 60px 10px 10px; color:blue;   font-size:18px;">
    </div>
```

## need to change class to id

```
<div id="emailSent" align="center" style=" margin:10px 60px 10px 10px; color:blue; font-size:18px;">
    </div>
```

Comment: but if I change it to an id, and since I will have multiple rows with the same id, then how will I access, say the div inside row 4??

Comment: You can't use an ID more than once anyways.  jQuery will always select the first ID it finds with that name.

Comment: That's exactly my point. I made a typo in my original post. I have my divs setup as .className. My question is how can I access those divs if what I ve tried does not get me access to those divs?

Comment: See my updated answer for a simplified example.  By the way, take that "display:none" inline CSS out.

Comment: can you explain why I should take the display:none out? what will this achieve? just trying to learn not trying to be arrogant

Comment: No worries man.  Display:none is going to hide the `replyDiv` block, so you can't hide something that's already hidden :)  In your original post you said `$(".replyDiv").hide();` but it's already hidden using that inline CSS.

Comment: Well, I can't take the display:none out, because at pageload, I want this div to be hidden. See, the user clicks on reply, the replyDiv is shown ONLY at this time. Then when they submit the reply, I want to hide the replyDiv again and show the emailSent div instead

Comment: You need to write clearer questions to begin with.  We don't know your design or assumptions.

Comment: true,true! I won't argue with that